# handle segments with in controller class in codeigniter 2.1

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i am stuck in segments in codeigniter because it is new to me,
the problem with my **login form**.

i gave the url in action like `action="blog/login/getLog"` and
my login form shows in the url like `blog/login`

i know that in controller class i just create a function like with the name `login` but i created my controller file like this:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

// Now See
function _remap( $method ){
    $this->load->view('header');

    switch( $method ){
        case 'about':
            $this->load->view('about');
            break;
        case 'login':
            $this->load->view('login');
            break;
        case 'services':
            $this->load->view('service');
            break;
    }

    $this->load->view('footer');
}
}//Close Class
```

but now don't know how to handle both segment like `login` and `login/getLog` .

**EDIT:** What happen exactly, when i click on the login button then i just see the login form according to `_remap()` and the url like `blog/login` and when i submitted the form and the url looking like `blog/login/getLog`, the login form still looking but i want to redirect it on success.. or want to detect the segment `getLog` if possible in the `case 'login':` if possible.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What exactly is happening wrong? are you getting the login case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending through the URL, just use uri class:

```
$var = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

If you are sending in a form, send the variable through the form. Perhaps a hidden field?

```
$var = $this->input->post('var_name');
```

**Edit**: I'm not quite sure why you are using _remap for this w/o routing to another function (you are only trying to call a view file instead)

This is how I would expect to see the login form:

```
<?php echo form_open('blog/login');?>
<input type="hidden" name="getLog" value"true" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Then in your Blog class i would rather put a function

```
public function login() {
    if($this->input->post('getLog') === "true") {
        //the form was submitted, let's check the login?
    }
    else {
        //probably don't need an else, but form isn't submitted
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

In case there are confusions and you actually want to use remap.  You can do it like this to get the variables also.

```
function _remap( $method ) {
  if ($method == ‘something’) {
     $this->something();
  } 
  else {
      $this->somethingelse();
  }
}

function something() {
  $var1 = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $var2 = $this->input->post('some_variable_name');
}
```

Comment: this won't solve because he is routing without putting any methods in _remap.

Comment: Which is why I said i'm not sure why he's trying to use remap.  He can just put function login instead, but added edit to show how to use remap.

Comment: @MikeCruz13 please don't mind but this is my first site in codeigniter that i said that i am new to codeigniter, i used `_remap()` because of rid from header and footer view to include every time :)

Comment: If you really just don't want to rewrite that $this->load-> call twice, you could make a function index() and call that instead. like blog/index/login.  You can name it something else, but index has the benefit of automatically being called when nothing else comes after the controller.  i.e. www.example.com/blog  in index, use the uri->segment class call like i showed above.

Comment: @MikeCruz13 due a lot of busy schedule still not implemented, this sunday i will try, i know the rules of the stackoverflow. i will come back and tell you about all if it will work or not, that's why i didn't marked it solved..

Comment: @MikeCruz13 Working Smoothly :), thanks a lot man and didn't knew about `$this->uri->segment()` this working well that i want..

Comment: Great! and don't worry, it took me a little time to get used to codeigniter too even after a long time of writing in PHP!  Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

// Now See
function _remap( $method ){


    switch( $method ){
        case 'about':
            $this->about(); <---------- here method (Add header, content, footer inside respective functions)
            break;
        case 'login':
            $this->login(); <------- here too
            break;
        case 'services':
            $this->service(); <----- here too
            break;
    }


}
}//Close Class
```

what you have done here is, you overrided the default behavior of URI by `_remap` function.

> The overridden function call (typically the second segment of the URI)
>   will be passed as a parameter to the _remap() function:

Simply, in most cases, the 2nd segment will become $method in the `_remap` function.

so your form action will become.

```
action = "<?php echo base_url('blog/login');?>"
```

add `index.php` if you haven't removed index.php from your url by htaccess.

---

**EDIT:**

As per your question,

> but now don't know how to handle both segment like login and login/getLog .

this is how you deal.

Any extra segments after the method name are passed into _remap() as an optional second parameter.

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
   // all other segments will be in $paramas array
}
```

Comment: you mean to say login form action on the same login page?? and what if i use `$this->login();` instead of `$this->load->view('login')` in `case 'login':` ??

Comment: i it possible with the above approach??

Comment: You need to use method in `_remap`. means `$this->login();` or any other functions.